# Accessory View in UITableView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, iphone-sdk-3.0, xcodebuild

I have a doubt in accessory view in UITableView. The doubt is

Is it possible to add more than one button in UItableviewcell using accessryView if so plz guide me.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You *could* use a custom view that has two buttons as subviews, and add this as the accessoryView, but you are probably better off with a custom UITableViewCell.

Comment: Thanks a lot buddy i fixed the issue through custom view.